# JQTouch form redirect

Tags: javascript, jqtouch, cordova

How might I implement a simple form redirect using JQTouch after hitting "submit"?

Thanks!

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "form redirect"? Usually, within JQTouch, you would handle input with Ajax.

Comment: thanks, I have a simple form that I POST the results to a PHP page on an external server.  Everything works great with the form and PHP, but I'd like to redirect the user to another page after hitting submit or even possibly to another div.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

In jqtouch you can submit a form through ajax, and the default behavior is to replace the current div with the result from the website.  For an example look at the [jqtouch demo page](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/tree/master/demos/main), in the Ajax samples, look at the Ajax post example.